# Masonry: Images stack vertically, one image each row

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am using Masonry in my webpage. The problem is that after the page loaded, all images stack vertically, one image in a row. I would like them to stack both horizontally and vertically. See [My Jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/shapeare/saonpswu/2/)

I use the following code in html:

```
<div class="container">

        <div id="items">
            <!-- the .box repeats several times -->
            <div class="box panel panel-default">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150/333333/ffffff">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    name：1<br>
                    publisher：2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>           

</div>
```

and the following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    var $container = $('#items');

    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        isFitWidth: true
    });
});
```

and also the CSS:

```
.box { margin: 5px; width: 214px; }

.box img { width: 100%; }

.panel .panel-heading {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 0;
    height: 150px
}
```

-------------------- Update ---------------------

The above code is just an abstraction of my webpage, in my first version of fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/shapeare/saonpswu/), I accidentally put `.box` into separate `#items`, therefore, the code didn't work. This problem is pointed out by @Skelly. Thanks, Skelly. Now the fiddle works for the above demo (http://jsfiddle.net/shapeare/saonpswu/1), however, my webpage still cannot work. Now I have put almost the same content as my webpage in the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/shapeare/saonpswu/2

Comment: So some of your jsfiddle's use angular.js and some don't. Which one is the code for your site that is not working?Clear up your question since you don't mention angular at all in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your HTML so that there aren't separate DIV's with `id="items"`

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150/333333/ffffff">
        <div class="panel-body">
            name：1<br>
            publisher：2
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150/333333/ffffff">
        <div class="panel-body">
            name：1<br>
            publisher：2
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150/333333/ffffff">
        <div class="panel-body">
            name：1<br>
            publisher：2
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150/333333/ffffff">
        <div class="panel-body">
            name：1<br>
            publisher：2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/OD2uHuKupr

Comment: Hi, thanks, it solved the problem in the demo. However, the above demo is just an abstraction of my webpage, I have updated my fiddle with the content from my actually webpage, but it doesn't work again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to mention that I am using Angular.js which probably caused this problem. I am now using the directive from http://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/ which resolved my problem.